Differences between Landauer formalism and Boltzman transport
I am trying to have an intuitive understanding of the differences between Boltzman transport and Landauer formalism.
In particular, while it is clear that the first measures the conductivity, thus the intrinsic part, while the second the conductance, thus the extrinsic part, I also understand that these cannot be related to one another at the atomic scale by
$$
    G = \sigma S/L \tag{1}
$$
Moreover, the conductivity depends on the relaxation time while the conductance does not. How are they actually related at the atomic scale? Why is G not depending on the relaxation time?

This won't be anywhere close to a full answer, just a few loosely stated ideas reflecting my understanding.
The first thing to note is that the semiclassical Boltzmann transport formalism and the quantum-mechanical Landauer formalism (or the extension to multi-terminal transport known as the Landauer-Büttiker formalism) for transport in mesoscopic systems  are constructed in entirely different ways, so arguably there is no expectation for them to match one-to-one. The textbook "Modern Condensed Matter Physics" contains good introductions to both formalisms.
The archetypical setting that Landauer's formula is derived in assumes a wire of width $W$ and length $L\gg W$, connected to leads/reservoirs on the left and the right side of the wire of interest. Further, one introduces a characteristic length between inelastic collisions, $l_\varphi$ and assumes $L\ll \varphi$ such that no backscattering occurs within the wire itself, only in the reservoirs, which are large enough to equilibrate the electrons. Then, Landauer's formula for zero temperature is obtained:
$$G=\frac{2e^2}{h}\bar{T},$$
where $\bar{T}$ is the transmission probability that an electron emerging from the left reservoir ends up in the right reservoir, and $2e^2/h$ is the conductance quantum accounting for spin degeneracy.
As argued in lecture notes by Dan Arovas, since scattering within the wire part is entirely elastic, we can associate any dissipation to processes occurring within the right reservoir/lead. But crucially, we do not need to concern ourselves with them if we only seek to understand the transport through the wire. Further, one can distinguish between the conductance of the sample (which consists of both wire and leads) from the intrinsic conductance of the wire by introducing a contact resistance in series with the wire resistance.
The total transmission can be decomposed as $\bar{T}=MT$, where $M$ is the number of channels and $T$ is the average transmission probability per channel. For large conductors, $M\propto S$, where $S$ is the cross-sectional area. If we also have that $L\gg l_\varphi$, such that ballistic transport no longer applies, it naturally follows that $T\propto 1/L$. (For more details, I recommend S. Datta's book "Quantum Transport: Atom to Transistor".) Putting these statements together,
$$G\propto MT \propto \frac{S}{L}$$
and we recover Ohm's law.
Thus far, I haven't said anything about the relaxation-time approximation, but perhaps the link is clear. In the relaxation-time approximation one assumes inelastic collisions occur at times separated on average by the relaxation time $\tau$. We can compare this to the Landauer formalism in the regime of diffusive transport, where we assumed backscattering backscattering occurs after an average distance of the mean-free path $l_\varphi$. In the semiclassical theory, where it makes sense to talk about the velocity of electrons (really wave packets), the quantities $\tau$ and $l_\varphi$ can then be related. As far as I can tell, this is rarely done in detail as either approach is usually more suited to the problem at hand, but a relevant reference that does exactly this [see Eq. (12)] is C. Jeong, R. Kim, M. Luisier, S. Datta, and M Lundstrom "On Landauer versus Boltzmann and full band versus effective mass evaluation of thermoelectric transport coefficients", J. Appl. Phys. 107, 023707 (2010).
